# Static IP breaks Network connection

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I am somewhat new to Linux. I am setting up a Web server and installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on an vSphere ESXi 5.5 host. I am connecting perfectly fine to the internet when using DHCP but when I apply my Static settings I loose the ability to connect to websites.

Whats weird is I can Ping google.com but if I try wget gooogl.com it hangs at connecting to google.com (google.com):173.194.43.32:80 and I get "failed: connection refused"

But if I am set to DHCP the connection resolves perfectly.
Thanks

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.1.2.25
gateway 10.1.2.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
search tsig.com
dns-nameservers 10.1.2.13 10.1.2.30
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to your question.

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is using your address?

Comment: I have checked but I will check again. This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Apparently I didn't check hard enough. but now I have to find what is holding that IP. I never allocated it to anything. Thanks for the help and sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Just so you don't think I am crazy. I set the ip to a different unused IP, I create a rule in the firewall for the new ip to have external access and now I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open network configuration file
`$ sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces` OR `$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Find and remove dhcp entry:
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

Append new network settings:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.254
```

Save and close the file. Restart the network:
`$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`

Comment: You still need dns-nameservers.